# javascript game - win by just tapping the key but not holding down the key the whole time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple game in the browser which purpose is for players to tap allocated keyboard keys (for example, player 1 needs to tap the key "A" and player 2 needs to tap the key "P"). The player who taps more times(there is 10 seconds for the challenge) wins.

The problem is, I only want the game to work if the key is tapped but not held down for the whole time. Because you can win by just holding down one key for the whole time. Is there a way to make it work so the players MUST tap but not hold down the keys?

Answer (score 3):

Key repeat repeats the `keydown` and (for some keys) `keypress` events, but not the `keyup` event. So to do what you've described, you listen for both the `keydown` and the `keyup` events, and only count a `keydown` as an actual keypress if you've seen a `keyup` since the last one.

But see [smartilabs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911810/157247) — as they point out, you probably can listen to *just* `keyup` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Simply listen only to keyup events, not keydown, example with jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/ja6h84bk/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function() { console.log('down') });
    $(document).keyup(function() { console.log('up') });
})
```

Comment: That's a very good point! You probably don't need to listen for `keydown` at *all*.

Answer (score 0):

use `keyup` event, here is an example, click **Enter** to see it.

```js
var n = 0;
document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        n += 1;
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = n;
    }
})
```

```html
<h1 id='count'>0</h1>
```